# SQL JOIN, optimization

Tags: sql, optimization, join

I am currently building a website on a single server. Database starts to grow reaching almost half a tera. I wonder how I could speed up SQL queries especially on join requests...

In fact I see that when I do a

```
SELECT * FROM table LEFT JOIN pofile on profile.id=table.id WHERE uid=useruid
```

table and profile are big tables (more than 5 millions inputs). But I wonder how the joint is performed and how it is optimized because in my case if I first select profile to uid=useruid I have only a hundred of lines and other conditions decrease table to a thousand of rows so join should be fast but not seems to be se case as join request takes about a second and where clauses ids, uids are index in tables.

Is there a way to optimize SQL joins ?

Comment: And your database engine is (the whole art of SQL query optimization depends on database engine and its version)? Could you show also exact  index definitions?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. An entire profession lives from doing that.

You should read about explain plans and indexes. Sometimes, you can reach a speed improvement of 1000% or more with that (depending on the db's current state, of course).

Comment: In respect of your answer, but i think this is not an answer because it is too general.

Comment: It points to the direction that should be taken to solve this problem (and related ones). This makes much more sense than playing around witzhout a plan. You'll need quite some general knowledge, there is no straight answer in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexed views. This boost your performance because of having balanced tree of joined table.

Answer (score 0):

It hugly depends on database engine. In case of your query does this work better:

```
WITH t AS (
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table
WHERE uid=useruid
) 
SELECT
  *
FROM
  t
  LEFT JOIN
    profile
  ON
    profile.id = t.id
```

Comment: hum I was working with select ... in select before but it was longer. Will try this one !